# Node JS Sequalize Get All

Tags: node.js, express, endpoint

I have this:

```
//file index.js
.
.
.

// Routes
app.get("/chat", async (req, res, next) => {  
  const list = await getAll();
  console.log("list: ", list);
  res.json(list);
});
 
.
.
.
const getAll = () => {
  sequelize.sync().then(() => {
    Chat.findAll().then(res => { 
        //console.log("resp: ", res);
        return  res;
      }).catch((error) => {
          console.error('Failed to retrieve data : ', error);
      });

    }).catch((error) => {
        console.error('Unable to create table : ', error);
    });
}
```

I just want get data of table `chat`, so I'm creating a simple endpoint to get it, so I check on `console.log("resp: ", res);` in `getAll()` and I saw the data of table chat on console, but I tested the endpoint `localhost:3001/chat` and I don't get it, so I tested `console.log("list: ", list);` on `app.get("/chat", async (req, res, next)` and I got `undefined`

what's wrong??

Comment: Function getAll not returting any result, just calling the sequelize. 
So "return sequelize.sync().then ... " should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using async function for the callback function as well.

```
    //file index.js
    .
    .
    .
    
    // Routes
    app.get("/chat", async (req, res, next) => {  
      const list = await getAll();
      console.log("list: ", list);
      res.send(list);
    });
     
    .
    .
    .
    const getAll = async () => {
      await sequelize.sync();
      const res = await Chat.findAll();
            return  res;
   }
```